# Contador en html y JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

Tengo un contador en html y javascripts funciona normal hace lo que debe

```js
var clicks = 0;

function clickME() {
  clicks += 1;
  document.getElementById("clicks").value = clicks;
  document.getElementById("bote").value = "0";
}

function clickME2() {
  if (clicks > 0) clicks -= 1;
  document.getElementById("clicks").value = clicks;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group text-white">
  <label for="clicks">Conteo</label>
  <input type="text" value="0" class="form-control" id="clicks" name="clicks" minlength="1" maxlength="3000" required><br>
  <div class="sumar" id="bote" onClick="clickME()" ;>+</div>
  <div class="restar" id="boty" onClick="clickME2();">-</div>
</div>
```

ahora mi problema esta en que cuando envia los datos los envia bien y me limpia el campo

```
function handleFormSubmit(formObject){
document.getElementById("clicks").value = "0";
}
```

colocando el contador en 0 de nuevo ahora cuando yo le doy al botón + en vez de comenzar de 0 me trae el último número que se ingreso si quedo en 5 comienza en 6 y no en 0. si alguien me puede apoyar como podria lograr que me limpie el campo completamente que cuando yo le debe + me comience en 0 y no en el último dígito que se quedó ingresado.

[image]

Ei se ve en la foto el último dígito ingresado fue 2 y cuando se le da guardar envía los datos bien y llega el número 2 sin problema pero cuando uno hace un nuevo conteo que presiona el + comienza en el 3 y no en el 0

Comment: La pregunta no tienen nada que ver con la hoja de cálculo de Google, es únicamente sobre HTML y JavaScript. Evita incluir contenido que no ayude la descripción clara de lo que se está preguntando. Ref. https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior

Comment: lo que esta viendo esta hecho en app scripts que es javascript oviamente pero la informacion se envia a la hoja de google sheet y la pantalla es un html desarrollado en el ambiente de google. y luego puesto como una implementacion web.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta jose. Está muy bien, pero la pregunta incluyendo las etiquetas deben centrarse en lo que se está preguntando, que en este caso es meramente HTML y JavaScript. En este caso el que se envía a una hoja de cálculo de Google, a cualquier otro lugar o que no envíe no afecta la pregunta ni la respuesta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema se debe a que el código usa una variable global pero esta no es reinicializada por la función `handleFormSubmit`. Una manera sencilla de resolverlo es al siguiente:

```
function handleFormSubmit(formObject){
clicks = 0;
document.getElementById("clicks").value = clicks;
}
```

Comment: gracias ruben era exactamente lo que buscaba lo adapte a mi código.  ahora si limpia mi campo a 0 cuando envio y no mi contador comienza de cero 
function handleFormSubmit(formObject){
  google.script.run.processForm(formObject);
  // document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
   document.getElementById("codigo").value = "";
    document.getElementById("tall").value = "";
  clicks = 0;
document.getElementById("clicks").value = clicks;

}

disculpe que respondo tan tarde pero el fin no tuve computadora agradecido con el aporte mi estimado. que tenga feliz dia y gracias a  todos.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta @josegarcia. No hay problema, de hecho te agradezco. Por cierto no tardaste tanto, he tenido casos que tardan más de un año en que se acepte  mi respuesta o tenga respuesta del autor de la pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

para hacer lo que tu dices, en vez de usar una variable como si fuese el valor del input para luego sumarlo o restarlo, lo que tienes que hacer es coger directamente el valor del input y pasarlo a integer para luego sumarlo o restarlo, te dejo un ejemplo.

```js
input = document.querySelector('input')

function sumar(){
  input.value = parseInt(input.value)+1
}

function restar(){
  input.value =  parseInt(input.value)-1
}
```

```css
button{
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="sumar()">+</button>
<input type="number" value="0">
<button onclick="restar()">-</button>
```